# How to build multiple npm packages for sharing?

Tags: node.js, npm, rollup, lerna

I'm trying to create a mono repository to host multiple small packages that I plan to deploy on npm. I use **Rollup** for the bundling part.

After many hours watching what others do, searching on the internet and experimenting, I've reached a point where I'm stuck and little push in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

---

I've created a minimalist demo project that I've hosted on GitHub so it's easy to experiment with. You can find it here:
https://github.com/Stnaire/my-lib

---

In the repository you'll find 3 packages in the `packages` directory:

- `config`: contains a *SharedConfiguration* service
- `container`: a wrapper around `Inversify` to have a statically accessible container with helper methods
- `storage`: a package containing a *StorageService* (normally for writing in the local storage, cookies, etc) and a *VarHolder* helper which is just a memory storage.

---

In each package there is a `package.json` (defining the npm package parameters) and a `tsconfig.json` for the build.

---

What I'm trying to do is the have a npm package for each of the packages, each allowing for the following types of usages:

1. **With a bundler** in a **TypeScript** environment

```js
import { SharedConfiguration } from '@my-lib/config';

// or ideally:
import { SharedConfiguration } from '@my-lib/config/shared-configuration';
// this way only this dependency is included, not the whole `config` pacakge
```

2. **With a bundler** in a **JavaScript** environment

```js
var SharedConfiguration = require('@my-lib/config');

// Or like above, ideally:
var SharedConfiguration = require('@my-lib/config/shared-configuration');
```

3. **By including the output JS file in the browser**

```html
<script src="my-lib-config.umd.js"></script>
<script>
   MyLibConfig.SharedConfiguration.get(...);
</script>
```

---

**What I tried**

I've created two branches in the demo repository, corresponding to two strategies.

**First strategy**: create aliases (branch `detailed-modules-resolution`)

In the `tsconfig.json`, I do:

```json
{
    "paths": {
        "@my-lib/config/*": ["packages/config/src/*"],
        "@my-lib/container/*": ["packages/container/src/*"],
        "@my-lib/storage/*": ["packages/storage/src/*"]
    }
}
```

This way I can import precisely what I need:

```js
import { SharedConfiguration } from '@my-lib/config/shared-configuration';
```

And because the aliases also correspond to the folder structure in `node_modules`, it should work for the end user with a bundler as well.

But this way I get warnings when building as UMD:

```
No name was provided for external module '@my-lib/config/shared-configuration' in output.globals – guessing 'sharedConfiguration'
No name was provided for external module '@my-lib/container/container' in output.globals – guessing 'container'
```

Creating a global alias for each import is out of question, thus the second strategy.

---

**Second strategy**: centralize all public exports (branch `centralized-imports`)

So the idea is simply to export everthing the package wants to expose to other packages in the `index.ts`:

```js
// packages/config/index.ts

export * from './shared-configuration';
```

Then in the build script, I do this:

```js
// scripts/build/builds.js

/**
 * Define the mapping of externals.
 */
export const Globals = {
    'inversify': 'Inversify'
};
for (const build of Object.keys(Builds)) {
    Globals[`@my-lib/${Builds[build].package}`] = Builds[build].moduleName;
}
```

Wihch creates the following object:

```json
{
    'inversify': 'Inversify',
    '@my-lib/config': 'MyLibConfig',
    '@my-lib/container': 'MyLibContainer',
    '@my-lib/storage': 'MyLibStorage',
}
```

This way umd builds are working.

But there is two main drawbacks:

1. You have very little control on what you import. You import a whole package or nothing. And if the package depends on other packages you can quickly import thousands of lines for a little service.
2. This creates circular dependencies, as in my example project.
   `SharedConfiguration` uses `VarHolder` which is in the **@my-lib/storage**. But this package also contain a `StorageService` which uses `SharedConfiguration`, creating a circular dependency
   because all the imports are based on the `index.ts`: **@my-lib/config** => **@my-lib/storage** => **@my-lib/config**.

I thought about using one strategy or the other depending if I build in `umd` or not, but it feels wrong.
It must be simplier way to handle all of this.

Thank you very much for reading all this.